# SQL complicated SELECT query

Tags: mysql, sql, select

I would like to have a select query, where I get all the games that a specific user played with the points of his and the opponents team.

[image: Entity relatioship model of my database]

<sup>*Entity relatioship model of my database*</sup>

**This is my current query:**

```
Select playsIn.userId,game.id AS "gameId", plays.won, team.points from game JOIN plays ON plays.gameId = game.id
 JOIN team ON team.id = plays.teamId JOIN playsIn ON team.id = playsIn.teamId WHERE playsIn.userId = 2
```

**The current query gives me this result:**

| userId | gameId | won | points |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | true | 19 |

**Problem:**
From this query I only get the points of my team, but I would also like to get the points of the other team. I don't know how to get the points of the opponents.

**The result should look something like this:**

| userId | gameId | won | pointsMyTeam | pointsOtherTeam |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | true | 19 | 14 |

Note: For a game there are always only 2 teams.

Thank's for helping out!

Comment: What have you tried so far? Where are you stuck? Please share more details, like the table structure, sample input data, the expected output corresponding to that input data

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you need to join to the other `plays` row for that game, the row that matches the game ID but does not match the team ID:

```
JOIN plays otherplays ON otherplays.gameId = game.id AND otherplays.teamId <> team.id
```

Then you can join that to the other `team` row:

```
JOIN team otherteam ON otherteam.id = otherplays.teamId
```

And then you can select `otherteam.points`.  By the way, please consider making `points` a column of the `plays` table instead of the `team` table.  By making `points` a column of `team`, you limit each team to having only one point value and therefore playing only one game.